# Exeption error when adding new custom Tab to Order View page in Admin

Tags: php, blocks, adminhtml, magento-1

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>    
    <adminhtml_sales_order_view>
        <reference name="sales_order_tabs">
            <action method="addTab">
                <name>order_view_tab_avans</name>
                 <block>ordersedit/adminhtml_order_view_tab_avans</block>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_view>
</layout>
```

Here is my `/app/code/community/MageWorx/OrdersEdit/Block/Adminhtml/Order/View/Tab/Avans.php`:

```
<?php
class MageWorx_OrdersEdit_Block_Adminhtml_Order_View_Tab_Avans
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
    implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
{    
    //change _constuct to _construct()
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('ordersedit/order/view/tab/avans.phtml');
    }

    public function getTabLabel() {
        return $this->__('Fraud Detection');
    }

    public function getTabTitle() {
        return $this->__('Fraud Detection');
    }

    public function canShowTab() {
        return true;
    }

    public function isHidden() {
        return false;
    }

    public function getOrder(){
        return Mage::registry('current_order');
    }
} 
?>
```

Here is my `/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/mageworx/ordersedit/order/view/tab/avans.phtml`:

```
<div class="entry-edit">
    <div class="entry-edit-head">
        <h4><?php echo $this->__('Hello its me!'); ?></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldset fieldset-wide">
        the content you want to show
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the Error I receive in the exception.log:

```
2016-08-01T15:00:29+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Ordersedit_Block_Adminhtml_Order_View_Tab_Avans' in /var/public_html/dev_sportsdirect_bg/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /var/public_html/dev_sportsdirect_bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('???????????????...')
#1 /var/public_html/dev_sportsdirect_bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('ordersedit/admi...', Array)
#2 /var/public_html/dev_sportsdirect_bg/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Tabs.php(112): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('ordersedit/admi...')
#3 [internal function]: Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs->addTab('order_view_tab_...', 'ordersedit/admi...')
#4 /var/public_html/dev_sportsdirect_bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(348): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 /var/public_html/dev_sportsdirect_bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(214): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateAction(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /var/public_html/dev_sportsdirect_bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#7 /var/public_html/dev_sportsdirect_bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#8 /var/public_html/dev_sportsdirect_bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#9 //var/public_html/dev_sportsdirect_bg/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#10 /var/public_html/dev_sportsdirect_bg/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(59): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#11 /var/public_html/dev_sportsdirect_bg/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(124): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->_initAction()
#12 /var/public_html/dev_sportsdirect_bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->viewAction()
#13 /var/public_html/dev_sportsdirect_bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#14 /var/public_html/dev_sportsdirect_bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#15 /var/public_html/dev_sportsdirect_bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#16 /var/public_html/dev_sportsdirect_bg/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#17 /var/public_html/dev_sportsdirect_bg/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#18 {main}
```

Here is what I have in the system.log:

```
2016-08-01T15:00:29+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/share/php/Mage/Ordersedit/Block/Adminhtml/Order/View/Tab/Avans.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/dev_sportsdirect_bg:/var/sentora/temp/)  in /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/dev_sportsdirect_bg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 145
```

I think the problem comes from not propery directory settings.

Note that it is important the order directory to be `OrdersEdit` not `Ordersedit` where it seems it is seeking the file.

I am not sure what is the problem, please help me out resolve this!

Comment: My answer hasn't helped you?

Answer (score 0):

Open the `config.xml` of your module and see the `<block>` section. Maybe the name of the block (alias) is not an `ordersedit`. If that is true, just use in your layout correct block alias from the `config.xml`.